# Indexing ROS2 topics/nodes based on host?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

I am wondering if I am able to index a topic based on the host IP? If I have 3 robots on one network and they all look for a `cmd_vel` how can I index what topic to publish to? Do I have to prefix them all with `/robot(n)_cmd_vel`? This is what ROS1 had to do, I thought ROS2 was better at this functionality.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334815/indexing-ros2-topics/nodes-based-on-host?/) by [PG_GrantDare](https://answers.ros.org/users/38516/pg_grantdare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2019-10-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-08**:
"based on host" or 'robot'? `host != robot` in the general case I would say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have not changed the basic communication model of anonymous publish subscribe between ROS 1 and ROS 2. To that end in general if you're on the same topic you're expected to want the same data.

You don't have to specifically modify each topic. There are tools you can leverage such as namespaces to push all the content into a lower namespace so as not to interfere with similarly structured robots in another namespace.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PG_GrantDare](https://answers.ros.org/users/38516/pg_grantdare/) on 2019-10-08**:
Thank you. Are there plans to have robots indexable by their hosts?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-10-08**:
In general no, that's not a pattern that we're designing for. The computational graph should be generally independent of what host it's running on. Many robots have one or more hosts and you might want to migrate processing to different hosts (maybe onboard, maybe offboard) transparently depending on your deployment and equipment capability. The assumption of a one to one association of host and robot does not hold for many use cases.

**Comment by [PG_GrantDare](https://answers.ros.org/users/38516/pg_grantdare/) on 2019-10-10**:
Ok, I understand that. What would be the standard to have a robot identifier given that it does have a one-to-one host relationship? Would it be using namespaces/ a prefix?